# Running another if statement when the first one fails

Tags: python, excel

I have some code that parses some html lines and pulls out a number (string) and it is all exported to an excel sheet. On some occasions, there is no number because the script is directed to the wrong line when it is looking to parse the html code and thus where it is looking to split the line does not exist. This then just leaves the cell in the excel spreadsheet blank.

I am trying to have the script check a different line in the html code to parse if the first one gives a result of None. This is what I am doing, but it does not have any effect:

```
if position0 > 0 :
        self.high0 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
        self.low1 = lines[line_number + 18].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
        if self.low1 == None:
               self.low1 = lines[line_number + 17].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I am not very good at programming in general, and I am sure there is something quite simple I am missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.low1` will never be `None` because it is a string (the last element after splitting on `'>'`). You want to compare against `''`

```
if self.low1 == '':
```

Or just compare its truthiness:

```
if not self.low1:
```

Comment: Ah, yes...perfect. Thanks! I will accept this as an answer once I am able.

Answer (score 1):

`str.split()` always returns a string, even if the split fails, so `self.low1` is *never* set to `None`.

Instead, I suspect you get a blank string instead:

```
if not self.low1:
```

would be `True` for both an empty string and `None`.

Note that normally, you should use `is None` instead of `== None`, because `None` is a singleton (only one copy exists during the lifetime of a Python program).

Comment: Something so simple :) Thanks!